# Удалить элемент из массива js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив и ф-ция, нужно удалять элементы с массива, я понимаю что delete удаляет элемент но после него образовывается «дырка», как его полностью удалить?

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 13, 349, 3483, 5432];
var doubledOdds = onlyDoubledOdds(myArr);
console.log(doubledOdds.length);
console.log(doubledOdds);
if (doubledOdds === myArr) {
  console.log('WTF?!');
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}

function onlyDoubledOdds(sourceArray) {
  var result = sourceArray;
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      delete result[i];
    } else {
      result[i] *= 2;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

а вообще оно выводит

9
[ undefined, 4, undefined, 12, undefined, 26, undefined, 6966, undefined ]
WTF?!

А нужно:
6
[ 2, 6, 14, 26, 698, 6966 ]
Ok

Comment: delete оператор удаляет из памяти, а не из массива. из массива удаляют процедуры, относящиеся к классу массива (`array`), например `pop`

Comment: а что должна делать приведенная функция?

Comment: Про splice знаю, не могу понять как правильно записать...                      if (i%2 == 0) {
    result.splice[i];
   }

Comment: @Webitek, а по какому принципу построен массив `А нужно:
6
[ 2, 6, 14, 26, 698, 6966 ]`?

Comment: все числа которые делятся на %2 с остатком 0 - удалились, а остальные *=2

Comment: <code>
function onlyDoubledOddsReduce(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) acc.push(el * 2);
    return acc;
  }, []);
} </code>
   вот так почти нормально работает, но почему-то число 13 пропускает, а вместо 3483 перемножает 5432

Comment: а почему он должен выбирать число 13? есть описание словами как из  исходного массива получить результат?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/

Answer (score 15):

Для удаления можно использовать специальные методы, такие как

- `shift` - удалит из начала
- `pop` - с конца
- `splice` - из середины

C помощью `splice` - как раз можно удалять элементы, вставлять элементы, заменять элементы – по очереди и одновременно.

Синтаксис таков:
**arr.splice(start[, countDelete[, elemInsert1, ..., elemInsertN]])**

т.е. удалить `countDelete` элементов, начиная с номера `start`, а затем вставить `elemInsert1, ..., elemInsertN` на их место. Если `countDelete` не указано, то отрежется все, начиная со `start` и до конца. Возвращает массив из удалённых элементов.

Пример с удалением выглядит так:

```
var arr = ["Привет", "тебе", "Миша"];
arr.splice(1, 1); // начиная с позиции 1, удалить 1 элемент
alert( arr ); //  осталось ["Привет", "Миша"]
```

а замещением:

```
var arr = ["Привет", "тебе", "мальчик", "Миша"];
// удалить 3 первых элемента и добавить другие вместо них
arr.splice(0, 3, "Здароф!")
alert( arr ) // теперь ["Здароф!", "Миша"]
```

Answer (score 5):

При применении оператора `delete` не изменяется свойство `length` массива, поэтому при использовании длины в цикле - разницы не будет.

Функция `onlyDoubledOdds` делает что-то непонятное, в зависимости от индекса элемента, причем меняет **исходный** массив, поэтому при сравнении возвращенное значение закономерно равно переданному, а не `"WTF"`

Если нужно отфильтровать массив - можно воспользоваться функцией [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),
если нужно получить массив на основе существующего, но с другими элементами - можно воспользоваться функцией [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),
если хочется за один проход, можно воспользоваться функцией [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Например:

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 13, 349, 3483, 5432];
var doubledOddsMapFilter = onlyDoubledOddsMapFilter(myArr);
console.log('doubledOddsMapFilter.length', doubledOddsMapFilter.length);
console.log('doubledOddsMapFilter', doubledOddsMapFilter);
if (doubledOddsMapFilter === myArr) {
  console.log('WTF?!');
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}

var doubledOddsReduce = onlyDoubledOddsReduce(myArr);
console.log('doubledOddsReduce.length', doubledOddsReduce.length);
console.log('doubledOddsReduce', doubledOddsReduce);
if (doubledOddsReduce === myArr) {
  console.log('WTF?!');
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}

function onlyDoubledOddsMapFilter(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.filter((el, i) => i % 2 != 0).map(el => el * 2);
}

function onlyDoubledOddsReduce(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    if (i % 2 != 0) acc.push(el * 2);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

**UPDATE:** так как начальное решение в вопросе было с ошибкой, то примеры выше ориентирующиеся на пример в вопросе так же ошибочны, проверяться должен **сам элемент** а не индекс.

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 13, 349, 3483, 5432];
var doubledOddsMapFilter = onlyDoubledOddsMapFilter(myArr);
console.log('doubledOddsMapFilter.length', doubledOddsMapFilter.length);
console.log('doubledOddsMapFilter', doubledOddsMapFilter);
if (doubledOddsMapFilter === myArr) {
  console.log('WTF?!');
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}

var doubledOddsReduce = onlyDoubledOddsReduce(myArr);
console.log('doubledOddsReduce.length', doubledOddsReduce.length);
console.log('doubledOddsReduce', doubledOddsReduce);
if (doubledOddsReduce === myArr) {
  console.log('WTF?!');
} else {
  console.log('Ok');
}

function onlyDoubledOddsMapFilter(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.filter(el => el % 2 != 0).map(el => el * 2);
}

function onlyDoubledOddsReduce(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el % 2 != 0) acc.push(el * 2);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не совсем все понял...буду сидеть разбираться

Comment: @Webitek, где конкретно не понятно? в примере с `filter-map` - сначала отбираются элементы у которых индекс нечетный(с помощью функции filter), затем по полученному массиву строится новый у которого элементы удвоены по сравнению с исходным массивом

Comment: @Webitek, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 13, 349, 3483, 5432];
myArr = myArr.map(el => el % 2 !== 0 ? el * 2 : el);
myArr = myArr.filter(el => el % 2 === 0 ? true : false);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: после первого `map` в массиве будут только четные числа, поэтому если убрать filter - ничего не изменится.